# Expectation for random variables having natural numbers as their range

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value

Let $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{N} $ be a r.v. Then $$ \mathbb{E} \{ X \} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(X > n) $$

Can i use the expression above to calculate the expected number of trials for getting 2 consecutive heads ,I am trying to do it this way but im getting stuck.

PS 
I know this problem can be solved by assuming that the expected number of trials is 'x' and proceeding further.

Comment: What is the connection between X and coin flip?

Comment: In the expression X is a random variable which corresponds to the trial in which we get 2 consecutive heads

Comment: I was thinking to frame the random variable that way

Comment: $E(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nP(X=n)$. How did you get your expression?

Comment: This expression is derived from the normal expectation expression just that it is specialized for natural numbers where as original expression for expectation is for real numbers.I just tried to use it i didnt derive it so the expression is correct I guess!

Comment: I think the definition of the random variable I chose is wrong it should be something else .

Comment: You can define X anyway you want.  I worked through the definition for E(X).  Mine and yours are equal.

Comment: No I wasnt talking about the expression but about what the random variable represents

Comment: I took that to be number of trials for getting 2 consecutive heads, which i think is wrong!!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with defining it to the number of trials until two consecutive heads appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the formula works for any random variable with non-negative integer values.  If $\ X\ $ is the number of tosses of a fair coin required to obtain $2$ successive heads, then $\ P(X>n)=\frac{F_{n+2}}{2^n}\ $, where $\ F_j\ $ is the $\ j^\mathrm{\,th}\ $ Fibonacci number.  Thus
$$
\mathbb{E}\left\{X\right\}=\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \frac{F_{n+2}}{2^n} = 6\ ,
$$
although this certainly doesn't seem to me to be the simplest way to compute this quantity.

**Answer to question below:** Why is $\ P(X>n)=\frac{F_{n+2}}{2^n}\ $?

Let $\ T_n\ $ be the outcome of the $\ n^\mathrm{th}\ $ toss, $\ \pi_n = P(X>n)$, $\ \pi_0(n) = P\left(\left\{X> n\right\}\cap \left\{T_n= \mathrm{tail}\right\}\right)\ $, and $\ \pi_1(n) = P\left(\left\{X> n\right\}\cap\left\{T_n= \mathrm{head}\right\}\right)\ $. Then
\begin{eqnarray}
\pi_n&=& \pi_0(n)+ \pi_1(n)\\
\pi_0(n+1) &=& \left(\pi_0(n) + \pi_1(n)\right) P\left(T_{n+1}= \mathrm{tail}\right)\\
&=& \frac{\pi_n}{2}\\
\pi_1(n+1) &=& \pi_0(n)P\left(T_{n+1}= \mathrm{head}\right)\\
&=& \frac{\pi_0(n)}{2}=\frac{\pi_{n-1}}{4}\\
\pi_0(1)&=&\pi_1(1) = \frac{1}{2}\\
\pi_0(2)&=&\frac{1}{2}\\
\pi_1(2)&=&\frac{1}{4}\ .
\end{eqnarray}
From these equations, it follows that $\ \pi_n\ $ satisfies the recurrence
$$
\pi_{n+1}=\frac{\pi_n}{2}+\frac{\pi_{n-1}}{4}\ .
$$
Therefore, if we put $\ \xi_n = 2^n\pi_n $, then $\ \xi_n\ $ satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence,
$$
\xi_{n+1} = \xi_n + \xi_{n-1}\ ,
$$
and it's also easy to check that $\ \xi_1=2\pi_1=2=F_3\ $, and $\ \ \xi_2=4\pi_2=3=F_4\ $.  It follows from this that $\ \xi_n = F_{n+2}\ $ for all $\ n\ge 1\ $, and so $\ \pi_n = \frac{\xi_n}{2^n}=\frac{F_{n+2}}{2^n}\ $.

Comment: Why is the probability P(X > n)= \frac{F_{n+2}}{2^n}\  can you explain a bit?

Comment: $\ \pi_1(n) = P\left(\left\{X> n\right\}\cap\left\{T_n= \mathrm{head}\right\}\right)\ $ , I think instead of P (X > n ) it should have been $\pi_0(n)\ $

Comment: @luG_0 I don't understand what you're suggesting. As I have defined it,
 $$\ \pi_1(1)= P(\{H\})=P(\{X>1\}\cap\{T_1=H\})\\
 \pi_1(2)= P(\{TH\})=P(\{X>2\}\cap\{T_2=H\})\\
  \pi_1(3)= P(\{HTH, TTH \})=P(\{X>3\}\cap\{T_3=H\})\ ,$$ and so on.  With that definition, argument seems to me to be correct.

Comment: according to your definition $\ \pi_0(n) = P\left(\left\{X> n\right\}\cap \left\{T_n= \mathrm{tail}\right\}\right)\ $, and $\ \pi_1(n) = P\left(\left\{X> n\right\}\cap\left\{T_n= \mathrm{head}\right\}\right)\ $.  but that isnt correct since if that is the case then $\pi_0(n)\ $ would always be equal to $\pi_1(n)\ $ but clearly thats not true

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't follow.  The event $\ \{X>2\}\cap\{T_2=T\} = \{TT,HT\}\ $, and has probability $\ \pi_0(2)=\frac{1}{2}\ $, whereas  $\ \{X>2\}\cap\{T_2=H\}=\{TH\}\ $ has probability $\ \pi_1(2)=\frac{1}{4}\ne\pi_0(2)\ $. For the only other $2$-long sequence of tosses, $\ \{HH\}\ $, $\ X\not>2\ $. I've no idea why you believe  $\ \pi_1(n)=\pi_0(n)\ $ for all $\ n\ $.